# Cassandra: Unable to find java executable

Tags: java, cassandra-2.0

I am starting to learn cassandra and downloaded the file from the [Apache Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/download/). When I navigated through the bin folder of the apache-cassandra-2.2.1/bin and run the command `cassandra` it gives me the error saying `Unable to find java executable. Check JAVA_HOME and PATH environment variables.`

But at the same path when I hit `java` I am able to see the java is accessible there. What should I do to get rid of this? I am using Windows OS.

Edit:
I rather used [Datastax windows installer](http://www.planetcassandra.org/cassandra) and now I see no error in running cqlsh.

Comment: I have never installed on windows, but see this, "I generally create an environment variable JAVA_HOME which points to java jdk and CASSANDRA_HOME which points to the root directory of Cassandra as shown above in the screen shot." from: http://www.varunpant.com/posts/install-apache-cassandra

Answer (score 7):

I was also facing the same problem. Actually, somewhere in installation scripts it adds "bin/java" to "$JAVA_HOME". In my case, java path was "/usr/bin/java" so I had to configure $JAVA_HOME=/user.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/
```

Answer (score 0):

Set JAVA_HOME:

Right click My Computer and select Properties.

On the Advanced tab, select Environment Variables, and then edit JAVA_HOME to point to where the JDK software is located, for example, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_02.

FROM:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/index.html

Comment: You set both java_home and cassandra_home?

Comment: Yes but no luck. I installed Datastax community using planetcassandra.org/cassandra and now all works fine. just downloading tar.gz did not work well.

Answer (score 0):

1. login with root because Cassandra will start with the root
2. `readlink -f $(which java)`
3. `vi ~/.bashrc`
4. `source ~/.bashrc`

please note: java version should be same on cluster nodes

BR// nitin.k